# Swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) in Tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have custom cell in table view. When I am running my code I am getting

below error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

My code is below:

```
class viewCompanyResultController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate    {

  @IBOutlet var uiTblCompanyResultView: UITableView!
  var companyName=""
  var countryCode=""
  var townCode=""
  var element=""

    var resultDict: NSDictionary=[:]
    var comapniesArr:[Company] = [Company]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.uiTblCompanyResultView.delegate=self
     self.uiTblCompanyResultView.dataSource=self
     self.comapniesArr.append(Company(orgName: "cbre", orgCode: "orgCode2", imageName: "3.png"))

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {

        return  self.comapniesArr.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell: CompantResultCell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CompantResultCell


            let companyResult=comapniesArr[indexPath.row]
             println("dgfdf \(companyResult.orgName)")


            cell.setCompanyCell(uiImgConComp: companyResult.imageName,lblCompanyName: companyResult.orgName)

            return cell
    }
}
```

Custome Cell Class

```
import UIKit

    class CompantResultCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var uiImgConComp: UIImageView!

     @IBOutlet var lblCompanyName: UILabel!


        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

        override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        }
        func setCompanyCell(imageName: String,lblCompanyName: String)
        {
            self.uiImgConComp.image=UIImage(named: imageName)
            self.lblCompanyName.text=lblCompanyName;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you see the error? Which line of code? Set an exception breakpoint and indicate where the error is otherwise nobody can help with this.

Comment: when a run the programm on custom cell constructor i get the erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom cell class looks perfect!

You need to unwrapped custom cell object in `tableView:(_cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method like below:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: CompantResultCell! = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CompantResultCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = CompantResultCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    }

    let companyResult=comapniesArr[indexPath.row]
    println("dgfdf \(companyResult.orgName)")


    cell.setCompanyCell(uiImgConComp: companyResult.imageName,lblCompanyName: companyResult.orgName)

    return cell
}
```

Edit:

Also unwrapped `UIImage` object in `setCompanyCell` method:

```
func setCompanyCell(imageName: String,lblCompanyName: String) {

    var cellImage = UIImage(named: imageName as String!) as UIImage!
    self.uiImgConComp.image = cellImage
    self.lblCompanyName.text=lblCompanyName;
}
```

Calling the function behaviour is different in Swift, not like in Objective C. Call this function as below line:

```
cell.setCompanyCell(companyResult.imageName, lblCompanyName: companyResult.orgName)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kampai the cell nil error gone but not it is coming same error in 'cell.setCompanyCell(uiImgConComp: companyResult.imageName,lblCompanyName: companyResult.orgName)' function...

Comment: Not clear. Can you give some more details. Do you get runtime error on `cell.setCompanyCell(....)` method?

Comment: i am having below function...                               func setCompanyCell(lblCompanyName: String)
    {
       self.uiImgConComp.image=UIImage(named: imageName)
        self.lblCompanyName.text=lblCompanyName;
      
    }   ...and in 'self.uiImgConComp.image=UIImage(named: imageName)'  i am getting ' unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' error...

Comment: i have above is my comment...

Comment: @Kampai...when i do this code........cell.setCompanyCell(uiImgConComp: companyResult.imageName,lblCompanyName: companyResult.orgName)... i get compilation error 'Extraneous argument label 'uiImgConComp:' in call' and when i remove that 'uiImgConComp:' than i get an errror on execution time 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' on this image line ' self.uiImgConComp.image = cellImage'

Comment: somehow ehen i remove image line code...i got same error on lable text too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67701/discussion-between-dhaval-shah-and-kampai).